# Add value to vertex array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, opengl

I want to make my vertex array dynamic. So that values would be added after every mouse event. When user drags his mouse I register mouse location coordinates. Coordinates is named 'loc'. And when user drags his mouse the 'loc' value is updated. So I want that when 'loc' is updated, coordinates would be **added** to vertex array. Still I can only do that when 'loc' is updated it rebuilds vertex array, so my vertex array always has only one coordinates (current 'loc' value).

My vertex array values are stored in GLfloat:

```
GLfloat vertexes[] = { loc.x, loc.y };
```

'loc' is registered in `- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event` by:

```
loc = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];
```

Vertex array is drawn in `- (void) drawMyShape` by:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
glPointSize(30);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);
glFlush();
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

`- (void) drawMyShape` is called after registering mouse events and adding them to GLfloat in `- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event` by:

```
[self drawMyShape]
```

---

Current code:

in .h file:

```
NSMutableArray *vertices;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *vertices;
```

in the beginning of .m file

```
@dynamic vertices;
```

in .m file in `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder`

```
vertices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in .m file in `- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event`

```
loc = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];
NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:loc];
[vertices addObject:locationValue];`
[self addValuesToArray];
```

in .m file in `- (void) addValuesToArray`

```
int count = [vertices count] * 2; 
NSLog(@"count: %d", count); 
int currIndex = 0; 
GLfloat GLVertices[] = {*(GLfloat *)malloc(count * sizeof(GLfloat))}; 
for (NSValue *locationValue in vertices) { 
  NSValue *locationValue = [vertices objectAtIndex:currIndex++]; 
  CGPoint curLoc = locationValue.pointValue; 
  GLVertices[currIndex++] = curLoc.x; 
  GLVertices[currIndex++] = curLoc.y; 
}
```

And it crashes on

```
NSValue *locationValue = [vertices objectAtIndex:i];
```

After crash in Log i see (*removed some parts of log because they are not important I think*):

```
sum: 2
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]
sum: 3
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]
sum: 4
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]
sum: 5
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]
sum: 6
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NSMutableArray to store your location objects dynamically.

Init the array at initialization phase :

```
NSMutableArray *vertices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Add vertices on mouse event :

```
loc = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];
[vertices addObject:loc]; // Assuming loc can be added as an object to the array
```

Convert to `GLFloat` array before drawing :

```
int count = [vertices count] * 2; // * 2 for the two coordinates of a loc object
GLFloat *glVertices = (GLFloat *)malloc(count * sizeof(GLFloat));
int currIndex = 0;
for (YourLocObject *loc in vertices) {
    glVertices[currIndex++] = loc.x;
    glVertices[currIndex++] = loc.y;        
}
```

Now you can use the `glVertices` array when drawing.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think its great solution. I only have one issue when trying to do that. I think its because loc is CGPoint. I get the `error Sending 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'; ` in [vertices addObject:loc];. How should I change CGPoint to get it working?

Comment: use NSValue to store the CGPoint in the array.

Comment: Why in LOG it always shows that there are no values? 

`NSUInteger sum = [vertices count];
    NSLog(@"count: %lu", sum);`

NSLog prints : `count: 0`

Comment: Are you sure nothing is added ? try using %d instead of %lu in NSLog

Comment: Still the same result. Strange

Comment: Can you post your code where you add the values to the array ?

Comment: oh, when you initialize the array do not declare NSMutableArray* again. just use vertices = [...].  And another thing in your draw function increase i before storing the y coordinate.

Comment: Thanks. But it crashes on `NSValue *locationValue = [vertices objectAtIndex:i];` now with error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, adress=0x0)`. Edited question with more info

Comment: your for loop is wrong. Use the syntax I showed you. count is twice the size of your array since each element is a location object and not one coordinate.

Comment: Edited question, updated code int `-(void)addValuesToArray` code.
And the same error on `GLVertices[currIndex++] = curLoc.y;` just `code=12`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13446/discussion-between-hockeyman-and-giorashc)